How Can I Fix Overcooked Noodles in My Pasta Recipe?
I recently tried making a new pasta dish using Trader Joe's Squiggly Noodles, but unfortunately, the noodles turned out overcooked and mushy. I followed the package instructions, but I think I might have left them in the boiling water for too long.
I’m looking for some advice on how to salvage this dish or how to prevent overcooking the noodles in the future. Specifically:

Salvaging the Dish: Is there any way to rescue overcooked noodles and improve their texture? Can I repurpose them into another dish or make the best of the situation?

Prevention Tips: What are some best practices to avoid overcooking pasta? Are there any specific timing or techniques I should follow to ensure the noodles remain perfectly al dente?



I don’t have any experience with it, but I’ve heard that Hawaiian pasta salad uses overcooked pasta… but I think it’s usually macaroni

One other thought on over cooked pasta… fry it to get some texture.  Maybe yakisoba, or mie goereng, or pasta pizza (the Italian leftovers dish… see https://www.cookingchanneltv.com/recipes/david-rocco/pizza-pasta-1958995 )

Please don’t post AI-generated content.

Unfortunately, you can't uncook noodles, if they are too soft there's nothing you can do to improve their texture. You may be able to improve the texture of the dish by adding another ingredient, in this recipes's case more vegetables would be the most likely choice. You'll only get so far with this though, overcooked noodles will still be very noticeable.
As for how to avoid that, when it comes to any noodles (including pasta) start timing as soon as you add the noodles to the water instead of waiting for the water to boil again. Then use the instructions as a guide, keeping in mind your desired texture may mean cooking for a shorter or longer time.
The kind of freeze-dried noodle you are using cooks quickly and can overcook in not much time at all. An extra sixty seconds may not make that much difference with a thick pasta but with thin noodles it means mush. So, be ready and get the noodles out as soon as the timer goes off - remember water does not have to be boiling for pasta to cook!
